# MySQL and the Java finaliser thread - High CPU consumption

Tags: java, hibernate, mysql-connector

My app (which uses hibernate) is running into high CPU consumption. When I take the thread dump, and analyze this, I see the following:

http-nio-80-exec-75 thread obtained com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedConnectionProxy's lock & did not release it. Due to that finalizer thread is BLOCKED as shown in the below graph. If Finalizer thread is blocked for a prolonged period, your application will experience memory problems.

The read time for the queries in question is really high, which is why the thread isn't releasing the lock. These are simple queries and cannot be tuned more. Other than increasing the core for better CPU, is there anything else that can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Is the read time high because of network latency or is it high because the queries return large resultsets?

Comment: These are count queries essentially, and with performance has taken a hit with an additonal 30K entires in multiple tables, is what am guessing.

Comment: FIRST Suggestion, ANALYZE TABLE each_table_used;  in ONE slow query to ensure current indexes are not corrupted and check your timing.

Comment: Consider POSTing A) One Slow Query, B) EXPLAIN SELECT (your query), C) SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; for each table used by this query D) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'tablename'; for each table used by this query -- for analysis,

Comment: Thank you, I needed to reduce the DB size and add cores to better the perf